# Promises not working on websocket when listening to messages on js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, async-await, promise

Upon receptiton of a message from a websocket server, I would like to call a promise function and wait for a respond to decide if it needs to threat another messages or not.

I tried to wrap a `connection.on('message', cb)` into a Promise but it doesn't help either. Here is the code:

```
let alreadyBought = false

const client = new WebSocketClient()
client.connect('wss://...')
client.on('connect', async (connection) => {
  connection.on('message', async event => {
    if (event.type === 'utf8') {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.utf8Data)
      if (!alreadyBought) {
        await trigger(data.p) // <--- not working
      }
    }
  })
})

async function trigger(price) {
  const order = await exchange.createLimitBuyOrder(config.currency, amount, price)
  console.log(order)
  alreadyBought = true
}
```

If I do a `console.log(event)`, I get this, check a timestamp:

```
{
  d: '{"t":1924698,"p":"1541.86", "T":1662043735929}'
}
{
  d: '{"t":1924699,"p":"1541.86","T":1662043735955}' // <-- At the same timestamp
}
{
  d: '{"t":1924700,"p":"1541.21","T":1662043735955}' // <-- At the same timestamp
}
{
  d: '{"t":1924701,"p":"1540.91","T":1662043735955}' // <-- At the same timestamp
}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `trigger()`, it's not properly waiting for the response before returning.

Comment: `alreadyBought` is not a function, why are you calling it with `()`?

Comment: @Barmar I've updated the code section

Comment: What does "not working" mean here? You get an error? What in your code is *proving* that something is wrong? Can you add debugging information?

Comment: @trincot I've updated a post with a logs. I've solved it with some "lockin" trick, but I'm not sure if it's really the best approach or not.

Comment: Don't know if callbacks + promises is the best recipe here (I'm strongly convinced it's not). It should be easier with observables. https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found a solution, by using a pricelocks while a Promise is processing.

```
let pricelock = false

const client = new WebSocketClient()
client.connect('wss://...')
client.on('connect', async (connection) => {
  connection.on('message', async event => {
    if (event.type === 'utf8') {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.utf8Data)

      if (!pricelock) {
        pricelock = true

        await trigger(data.p).then(() => {
          pricelock = false
        })
      }
    }
  })
})

async function trigger(price) {
  await exchange.createLimitBuyOrder(config.currency, amount, price)
}
```

I will leave a post open in case there is a better solution.

Comment: This will have different behaviour: here `trigger` can be called multiple times (each time `pricelock = false` is executed, it is allowed again), while in the original post, `alreadyBought = true` will prevent `trigger` from ever running again from that moment onwards.

Comment: @trincot you were absolutely right ! I will update my answer soon. thanks